# Compressão gzip utilizando servidor Apache

Tags: html, apache, gzip

Como habilitar a compactação gzip no Apache? Dei uma olhada e vi que é pelo `htaccess`, mas cada artigo que leio passa uma instrução diferente. Existe algum material, artigo ou coisa do tipo que possa me dar uma direção?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, acho que este artigo pode possuir o que você esta procurando:

[How To Optimize Your Site With GZIP Compression](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/)

Você deve adicionar no seu htaccess o seguinte código:

```
# comprimir texto, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Ou, comprimir alguns tipos de arquivos pela extenção:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

Foi o mais didático que encontrei sobre o assunto, espero que seja útil.

Comment: Caso não funcione corretamente me avise, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
```

Há uma ótima referência para este recurso e outras otimizações nos links abaixo:

- [Gzip Components](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip), no Yahoo Developers
- [Enable Compression](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload?hl=pt-BR#GzipCompression), no Google Developers